# Есть ли в PHP глобальный объект (как объект window в JavaScript)?

Tags: php

Привет.

Есть ли в *PHP* глобальный объект, в котором лежат все встроенные методы, все пользовательские функции, объекты, переменные..., внутри которого и происходит само программирование на *PHP*? В джаваскрипте таким объектом является объект *window*.

Хочу разобраться, что же такое программирование на *PHP*. Например, для сравнения, программирование на джаваскрипте - это манипуляции с "листьями"-объектами дерева BOM - «Возьми один лист-объект дерева BOM, что-то с ним сделай, результат запиши в другой  лист-объект...».

Comment: Нет. Нельзя прокидывать принципы работы из одного языка в другой. Это верный путь к быдлокодингу.

Comment: у вас в голове какая то каша, извините. Даже и не знаю, что посоветовать.

Comment: нет никакой каши. так что не извиняйтесь

Comment: В общем случае, в JavaScript нет никакого window. В реализации JS в браузерах, да, есть, но это же далеко не весь JavaScript.

Comment: window нет в ECMAScript, а JavaScript - ECMAScript + браузер. так что, в джаваскрипте есть window . JavaScript - это реализация ECMAScript в браузере

Comment: @Dimon, в node.js тоже нет `window`. По вашей логике там и не JavaScript вовсе.

Comment: по моей логике там ECMAScript

Answer (score 1):

Есть супер глобальные переменные такие как $_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER, $_SESSION, $_COOKIE и т.д. но сравнивать два языка невозможно т.к.:

1. js - функциональный язык, php - больше процедурный
2. js(тот с которым вы работали) - выполняеться в браузере, php - на сервере
3. js - вы оперировали DOM деревом(а не BOM символом), php - не оперирует DOM деревом он генерирует разметку
4. js - многопоточен, php - однопоточен

Comment: В JavaScript нет многопоточности.  Там происходит некое её эмулирование и что-то подобное

Comment: в джаваскрипте можно работать не только с DOM-деревом. например, я пишу var x=10; - в дереве BOM добавляется "листик"-свойство x, которое ссылается на примитивное значение 10. в джаваскрипте 3 дерева есть - BOM, DOM, CSSOM.

Comment: ладно DOM и CSSOM понятно что имеют древовидную структура, но сомневаюсь что BOM имеет. Хотя я не селён в js @Dimon

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да будем говорть точнее асинхроность т.е. выполнения частей программы паралельно. Я думаю так будет грамотнее.

Comment: BOM - это дерево с корнем window, в которое "вплетаются" DOM, CSSOM, переменные пользователя, функции пользователя, встроенные функции и еще куча всего

Comment: @Naumov, Сам JavaScript абсолютно точно однопоточен (разве что вы используете хаки конкретной среды выполнения Web-workers или node fibers или что-нибудь еще).

Comment: @Dimon, раз вы уже откопали термин BOM, то стоило хотя бы разобраться, что это. По всей видимости по BOM вы понимаете Browser Object Model (`navigator`, `location` и прочее). Если это так, то никакой DOM туда не _вплетается_.

Comment: у каждого свое понимание. мое понимание может быть в чем-то ошибочное. как и ваше. истинное понимание - только у разработчиков джаваскрипта. вот они реально понимают, что к чему на 100 процентов. а мы можем только догадываться. короче, не хочу ни с кем спорить. вопрос я задал другой.